# Form won't shrink down to the width of my iPhone screen

Tags: html, ios, css, forms

The note making form on my site is too wide and causes the rest of the page to shrink, see flickr. I can't figure out why, but I think it may be to do with the use of the `fieldset` element from looking at other questions. But that's actually the right width?

The form can be found at https://jonnybarnes.uk/notes/new

Pertinent code, html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<form action="/notes/new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" id="newnote">
  <fieldset class="note-ui">
    <legend>New Note</legend>
    <label for="in-reply-to" accesskey="r">Reply-to: </label><input type="text" name="in-reply-to" id="in-reply-to" placeholder="in-reply-to-1 in-reply-to-2 …">
    <label for="note" accesskey="n">Note: </label><textarea name="note" id="note" placeholder="Note"></textarea>
    <label for="webmentions" accesskey="w">Send webmentions: </label><input type="checkbox" name="webmentions" id="webmentions" checked="checked">
    <label for="twitter" accesskey="t">Twitter: </label><input type="checkbox" name="twitter" id="twitter">
    <label for="photo" accesskey="p">Photo: </label><input type="file" accept="image/*" value="Upload" name="photo" id="photo">
    <label for="locate" accesskey="l"></label><input type="button" name="locate" id="locate" value="Locate">
    <label for="kludge"></label><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="geo-status"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    width: 100%;
}
fieldset {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

flickr: https://www.flickr.com/photos/22212133@N03/15659029727/

Comment: An image can be helpful but the code needs to be posted in the question for people down the road with the same or similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to accomplish this is to actually use bootstrap if you are not really familiar with CSS Media Queries, or just want a quick and dirty job done.

If you want to do a custom job then you can add your own media queries with custom widths for each device you believe will be used for your form:

Example:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape)*/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Where you see /* Styles */ you can add your custom styles across the board for each query.

Great site that has helped many people with MQs is http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not sure if this is what his problem is. If you look at his site in mobile form all of the content is shifted over to the left for no immediately obvious reason, I.e. it doesn't look to be the fault of a media query or something.